# Has anyone used HBase, Tornado, Cassandra or HipHop with Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, cassandra, hbase, hiphop

I have a Drupal application that has a very large recordset, almost half a million nodes (475,181). Even simple joins are becoming too time consuming (3-10s), and we are becoming increasingly dependent on Memcached. I wonder if anyone has used the same technologies that Facebook is using with Drupal.

Comment: Simple Joins shouldn't take that long, even with 500k+ nodes, can you detail some more of your setup, Pressflow/Drupal, Hardware, DB, etc?? Memcached reliance (at scale) is a fact of life IMO but those joins are taking to long I think and there will be ways you can optimise the queries and the DB. What are your results when you vertically scale the DB Head?

Comment: Something as simple as select count(nid) from node_access takes 4 seconds on my development machine. Although production servers are much faster, they are also serving many page views per second. Sorry that I don't have another query at hand.

Comment: Whatever these fancy technologies are, it might take a while to integrate them into Drupal, and even more to consider stable enough for production use. This is more a question for the future and less for the present.

Comment: Read these two articles about Drupal 7 and HipHop for PHP: http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/17/drupal-hiphop-for-php-vs-apc-benchmark/ http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/19/drupal-7-download-hiphop-for-phps-compatible-source-codes/ From there you can download modified source codes of Drupal 7 so it can be compiled with HipHop for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: Not yet, but there is significant work being done on HipHop and a nosql database named MongoDB. More on those below.

As others have mentioned I would first make absolutely sure that your database tables are optimized properly, indexed and that your database has sufficient resources. If your database is choking on under 500k rows it's likely that there is something wrong. (We have over 150k node, about 600k rows in our node_revisions table and because the nodes have multiple images over a million rows in some of our cck tables.) I'm no MySQL expert and was able to get the database query times to under a hundred milleseconsds for most of our queries.) 
Here are the steps I would take before looking into Switching to a different db engine. (from easiest to hardest)

1. look for places that you need indexes. The most likely places are tables that have nid, vid or where there are a lot of queries that use a field value in the where, and any of the columns in your joins. This is where I got 80% of the improvement. Adding too many indexes can slow down inserts and deletes, but they are very simple to add, and remove.
2. Consider switching to INNODB it's almost always faster than the standard drupal 6 myisam. This is a super easy change.
3. Confirm that your my.cnf is set up properly. If you haven't changed it, it's probably wrong. The settings that ship with most distributions of MySQL are very, very conservative, and probably wrong for your environment.
4. Add RAM, if you have switched to INNODB adding RAM can make a huge difference in your performance, even without MySQL loves RAM.
5. Switch to pressflow if you can. It fixes a number of things that slow down regular drupal.
6. If you are still having problems look to moving away from CCK and created your own content types.
7. Review and optemize your views queries. Views isn't terribly efficient and you can sometimes make  very big headway by modifying the queries.

[Here](http://2bits.com/drupal-performance/presentation-34-million-page-views-day-92-million-month-one-server-and-drupal.html) is a great article on how much can be achieved with drupal and 1 single server.

If none of that works here's a few links regarding some of the newer haute technogogies that people are playing with. The most promising is MongoDB, and if you have the development resources to use it on a project I envy you. (It's still a little new new and unpolished for the small shop we are, but I can't wait to sink my teeth into it.)

[drupal and hiphop](http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2010/02/03/making-drupal-pressflow-more-mundane)

[drupal and Mongodb](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb) - there is also a great talk in the sessions from drupalcon SF (last year)

Comment: I just installed it locally today on my machine to "sink my teeth into it", it was so easy to setup and use! Now I'm on my way to trying the Drupal module. Regarding MySQL I have a dedicated sysadmin who has tweaked MySQL for better performance (don't ask me what he did). Today I spent half-day looking for missing indexes in the database and most tables had indexes already, custom and CCK indexes. I added indexes where they were none. We are already using Pressflow with Varnish, Memcached and a CDN. What slow downs the site is the relative amount of page views in relation to data.

Comment: "I just installed it" I was referring to MongoDB.

Comment: I'm still betting that you can get more out of MySQL. Not to doubt your sysadmin. . . but at 500k nodes it still sounds a little fishy that you are having 3-6 second queries. However working with MondoDB is definately more fun than MySQL. . . :)

Comment: In Drupal you seldom query the node table by itself, you generally join 2 to 7 tables, or more, depending on what data you want. So it's not 500k records that MySQL is looking through, it's generally much more.

Comment: I've heard there's also MariaDB, which is like a mix of MySQL with Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize HipHop and Tornado aren't database-software, right?

However, the db is almost like the core of a CMS, so when you have to change it to another system (well, actually even more, SQL to NoSQL) you should consider building a new / using another CMS rather than editing the Drupal-core.

Comment: Both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 cores run on top of a database abstraction layer - http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/group/database/6. In theory Drupal's db abstraction layer is pluggable, and as is, you could run it with postgreSQL, to give an example.

Comment: Still, it's based on a SQL-database. HBase and Cassandra are NoSQL-based databases so you aren't able to use the abstraction-layer.

Comment: Many parts of Drupal 7 are pluggable and you can store the information in an NoSQL db instead of SQL, see for example http://drupal.org/project/mongodb which allows to store session, fields, caches and so on in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience on that topic but https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183/real-world-experience-in-scaling-and-tuning-performance surely looks full of useful information.

Comment: That link is still closed to the general public.

Comment: Sorry, it should be accessible in a few days.